# How to embed shortcode in revolution slider button

Tags: slider, wordpress-theming, shortcode

add want to add following shortcode to my wordpress site(http://amazoeve.in/) revolution slider's button  Read more.
[ninja_forms_modal_form id=2 text_link="Click here to fill out out form"]

Basically this shortcode is of nija form modal.

Also , I want a register button in the menus nav bar . on its clieck i want same modal to open.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this from the HTML editor. You will have to access the backend PHP code and write the following PHP code for it,

```
<?php
  echo do_shortcode( '[ninja_forms_modal_form id=2 text_link="Click here to fill out out form"]' );
?>
```